# Qt -- How to set a QBrush for a QGraphicsItemGroup?

Tags: c++, qt, qgraphicsscene

I'm trying to create an interface for myself on Qt and I need a few rectangles over a DICOM image (a magnetic ressonance image), so they need to be some  color other than black but I can't find a way to set a brush for the QGraphicsItemGroup I'm using to keep the rectangles organized.

QGraphicsScene lets me add a QRect associated to a QBrush individually with

```
QgraphicsScene *scene = new QGraphicsScene();
QRectF rect = QRectF(QPoint(1,2),QPoint(3,4));
scene->addRect(rect, QBrush(Qt::red)); // using red as example
```

but adding each rectangle individually would make it all too messy and probably way slower. I need a way to set a QBrush for the rectangles but using QGraphicsItemGroup to be added to the QGraphicsScene.

Comment: You can use QGraphicsPathItem and add as many rectangles into it as you want.

Answer (score 0):

Why can you not reimplement QGraphicsItemGroup and inside have a function called:

```
void ReimplementedQGraphicsItemGroup::SetRectangleBrush(const QBrush& brush)
```

and inside that function iterate over every rectangle you have added to the group setting the brush

```
QgraphicsScene *scene = new QGraphicsScene();
ReimplementedQGraphicsItemGroup ReimplGraphicsGroup = new ReimplementedQGraphicsItemGroup()

// First rect
QGraphicsRectItem rect(1,2,3,4);
rect.setBrush(QColor(Qt::red);
ReimplGraphicsGroup->AddRectangle(rect);

// Second rect
QGraphicsRectItem rect2(5,6,7,8);
rect2.setBrush(QColor(Qt::blue);
ReimplGraphicsGroup->AddRectangle(rect2);

// add reimplemented graphics item group to scene
scene->addItem(ReimplGraphicsGroup);

void ReimplementedQGraphicsItemGroup::SetRectangleBrush(const QBrush& brush)
{
    foreach (QGraphicsRectItem rect, m_ListRects)
    { 
        rect.setBrush(brush);
    }
}

class ReimplementedQGraphicsItemGroup : public QGraphicsItemGroup {
    // a member of ReimplementedQGraphicsItemGroup
    QList<QGraphicsRectItem> m_ListRects;
}



void ReimplementedQGraphicsItemGroup::AddRectangle(QGraphicsRectItem rect)
{
    addToGroup(rect);
    m_ListRects.append(rect);
}
```